# Run/Debug Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to get my head around passing information from one Controller to another and back again. I watched a couple of youtube videos and found one that helped. I then downloaded his sample project from Github (https://github.com/JaretWright/GUIDemo) but I am having trouble running the project. I am using IntelliJ CE.

When I open up the "Run" menu I get the run option shown in the image below:

[image: Run menu]

IntelliJ then presents me with the option to "Edit Configurations" as shown in the image below:

[image: Edit Configurations]

When I click on that I get the following screen:

[image]

I select "Application" because i am sure that it is none of the other options. I then try and set the "Main" class IntelliJ prompts me to either search by name or by project. When I select to search by name I get the following options (from which I am unsure as to which to select):

[image]

And when I select to search by project IntelliJ will not allow me to select the class file that I know contains the "main" method as shown in the image below:

[image]

I don't know what to do, and I have scoured the net for some answers but I find nothing I can get to grips with. The folder structure for the project is shown in the image below:

[image]

I have also noticed that the class files do not appear as they would if I had created the project from scratch. On the ".java" files the icon shows a "J" in a red disc as shown below:

[image]

Instead of the usual "C" in a blue disc as shown below:

[image]

Can someone please help, or point me in the direction of some help.

Thanks in advance of any help offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ does not recognize the folder your class files are in as java sources. Right click on the "src" folder then "Mark directory as" and finally sources root.

[image]

Then IntelliJ should treat them as classes and build your project. Then either open the class containing your main-method and press the green play button next to the main method to run it.

[image]

Alternatively, you can right click on the class and then click "Run ${Application}.main().

[image]

And finally this should also enable you to setup a run configuration as described in your original question by now finding the GUIDemo class as main class.

[image]

Note that project SDK needs to be setup as described in @Loading...'s answer.

Hope that helps and enjoy IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make note, this project seems to be using older build technology called [ant](http://ant.apache.org/). I am not sure if this has any impact on Intellij as I have not used ant with CE version.

I am wondering if you have setup your `Project SDK` correctly within Intellij.

If you can open up your `Project Structure` window (shown below), you should see your `Project SDK` defined.
[image]

My hope is that you do not have an SDK defined and that is why your icons are the orange `j` instead of the usual blue `C`.  If it is not defined this should hopefully allow things to fall into place and for Intellij to recognize your main class (assuming CE version has ant support which I am not sure).

Comment: I had another look through and could not see a reference to "ant".Can you point me to where you saw that referenced please.

Comment: The `build.xml` file is usually consumed by ant

Comment: Ah! I see. Thanks for the tip. Will keep that in mind in the future. Are there any references on the net I can go to read up about "ant" that you would recommend.